# Rails quiz app getting results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, radio-button, nested-forms, nested-attributes, form-for

I'm trying to make a rails quiz application and am having a problem.
I'm using the nested_forms gem and I can normally create quizzes.
Here is the code for creating quizzes:

_form.html.erb:

```
<%= nested_form_for @quiz do |f| %>

    <%= f.text_field :name %>

    <%= f.fields_for :questions do |question_form| %>

        <h5>Question</h5>

            <%= question_form.text_field :question %>

            <%= question_form.text_field :option1 %>

            <%= question_form.radio_button :trueoption, 1 %>

            <%= question_form.text_field :option2 %>

            <%= question_form.radio_button :trueoption, 2 %>

            <%= question_form.text_field :option3 %>

            <%= question_form.radio_button :trueoption, 3 %>

            <%= question_form.link_to_remove "Remove" %>
    <% end %>


        <%= f.link_to_add "Add a question", :questions %>

        <%= f.submit "I'm Done!", class: "button" %>

<% end %>
```

This works perfectly, the quiz is created and saved.
But then when trying to solve the quiz the problems occur.
When I go on a show view of a quiz (like quizzes/8) I'm showing the quiz normally with this:

```
            <%= nested_form_for @result do |f| %>

                    <% @quiz.questions.each do |question| %>
                        <%= f.fields_for question do |q| %>
                            <div class="panel">

                                <h2><%= question.question %></h2>
                                <h5><%= q.radio_button :trueoption, 1, id: question.id %><%= label :trueoption_option1, question.id %></h5>
                                <h5><%= q.radio_button :trueoption, 2, id: question.id %><%= label :trueoption_option2, question.id %></h5>
                                <h5><%= q.radio_button :trueoption, 3, id: question.id %><%= label :trueoption_option3, question.id %></h5>


                            </div>
                        <% end %>
                    <% end %>
            <%= f.submit %>
        <% end %>
```

And it shows each question normally, like it should. But what doesn't work are the radio buttons; it's like they are all the same, only 1 can be checked out of all. What is the problem?

Here are the controllers:

quizzes_controller.rb:

```
class QuizzesController < ApplicationController
def index
  @quizzes = Quiz.all
end

def new
  @quiz = Quiz.new
  3.times do
    question = @quiz.questions.build
  end
end

def create
  @quiz = Quiz.create(params[:quiz])
  if @quiz.save
    redirect_to @quiz
  else
    render :action => :new
  end
end

def show
  @quiz = Quiz.find(params[:id])
  @result = Result.new
end
end
```

Results controller:

```
class ResultsController < ApplicationController
def new
  @result = Result.new
end

def create
  @result = Result.create(params[:result])

  if @result.save
    redirect_to @result
  else
    render action: :new
  end
end

def show
  @result = Result.find(params[:id])
end
end
```

And the models:

Quiz.rb

```
class Quiz < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :questions_attributes

  has_many :questions

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions, allow_destroy: true
end
```

Question.rb

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :option1, :option2, :option3, :trueoption, :quiz_id, :question

  belongs_to :quiz
  has_many :answers
end
```

Result.rb

```
class Result < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :question_id, :trueoption, :question_attributes

  belongs_to :question

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :question
end
```

So basically, what it does is it saves only 1 result instead of each one seperately (nested form), but it should save a result for each question specifically.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your model you have defined `Result belongs to Question`  therefore only one question is stored for your result.

Update your relation :

```
result has_many question
 question belongs_to result
```